# What's the next step in troubleshooting my electric water heater?

Tags: water-heater

We have a SpaceSaver (Model number: SS012SEB15), single-element 120v/1500w hot water heater which worked great until one day it went completely cold.

- First thing was I tested the voltage to the unit. It tested fine (120v).
- Next - did continuity test on the element and that tested good.
- Did voltage test going into, and, coming out of, the thermostat, and that tested good.
- Replaced element and thermostat anyway, still didn't work. (yes, I made sure to allow the tank to fill up, and the air to drain before turning on the power again)
- Double checked the thermostat's reset button, still no go.

What do I check next?  I am totally frustrated and lost at this point, but I don't want to shell out for a new tank since ours is not leaking or anything.

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbzjab1kq2tlcu6/IMAG1154.jpg]

[image]

Comment: Have you set the thermostat correctly and wired it around the right way? You want it to switch off when the temp rises to the right temp.  It might be set to switch off when the temp rises above a set temp.

Comment: Yeah, First I only replaced the element. Then when that still didn't heat, I tried replacing the thermostat too.  After replacing the thermostat, I double checked the voltage coming out of the thermostat and into the element, and it tested just fine...

Comment: what is the actual water temperature on full-hot (in degrees) and how does that compare to full-cold? and air temperature near the unit?

Comment: full cold is quite cole... e.g. you can drink it without refrigerating it and it would taste cold. when it worked, hot was quite hot, e.g. you couldn't run your hands under "full hot" without adding a bit of cold ...

Comment: what are the 3 temperatures now? in degrees. most any kind of garden room thermometer will do. It would also help to have the model number and age of the unit.

Comment: does the unit actually draw electricity when fully hooked up and 'running'?

Comment: also, since your old element tested good, you can test all the the circuitry and electronics at once, by hooking the old one up but not installing it into the unit, then turn the unit on.

Comment: Mike - my multimeter test at the element/thermostat reads 120v - so based on that I am assuming it is "drawing" electricity.

RE: the 3 temperatures - I am not on site right now, it is at our summer home / cottage. ALso, to test it like you most recently suggested - wouldn't that cause the element to burn up immediately?  Not sure I follow that last suggestion...

Comment: It would burn up eventually.  If worried, you could submerse the element in a pail of water, let the unit 'run' for 10 minutes, turn off the unit and touch the element to see if it is warm.

Comment: Also added model number and age to the original question...

Comment: SpaceSaver (Model number: SS012SEB15), single-element 120v/1500w

Comment: A 10 gal tank ought to empty quick enough to just drain, pull the element, and see how hot the element is.  If it is not hot, or at least warm, then despite the results of  previous electrical tests, the problem is electrical.

Comment: yeah I am heading back out there tomorrow after work, and I plan to complete run through ALL of the electrical tests again.  However, I suspect that, as before, I will go out and test the voltage coming out of the thermostat and to the element, and like before, it will read 120v. In that case, doesn't that indicate that the element is getting power?

Comment: I can't answer that directly, but maybe someone else here has that knowledge.  My suggestion was to skip the component tests and their logic, and just do an end-to-end test which would also test the connections.  I believe an alternate model number lacks a zero: SS12SEB15 such as here: http://www.gswpartsonline.com/model/A1229  I found the owners's manual here: http://www.gsw-wh.com/Docs/61515.1P.pdf  It looks like the element is mounted on the top, so no need to drain, just kill the circuit breaker and remove.

Comment: What do you mean by "end-to-end test" vs. a component test?

Yeah- i saw that manual... but our element is on the bottom... so it has to be drained :(

Comment: Odd that it does not match the manual.  Even the diagram of the side-drain model shows the element on top. .  End-to-end in the sense that it is all encompassing, everything in the electrical circuit being tested all at once, from one end to the other, including connections, and the test is functional (is the element hot?)

Comment: ok so is it safe if I take the element out (having it still wired up) and, say, dangle the "coil" part into a pan of water... and then fire up the power?  obviously it should heat up right?   I just need to find out the right way to do it without ruining any components or electrocuting myself.

Comment: here is an image of the setup... note the thermostat/element cover is near the bottom:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/lbzjab1kq2tlcu6/IMAG1154.jpg

Comment: Nothing with electricity is safe.  I'd do it with a plastic pail, turning off the power and feeling the element at 1,2,4,8,12 minutes.  But since the tank is so small, I'd do the run/drain/remove method first.

Comment: ok makes sense... going to give it a go tomorrow after work. Thanks for all of your help so far... will post results.

Comment: For convenience, i'd install a valve just upstream of the cold water inlet TEE that also acts as a drain.  In addition to being a convenience, it would also let you get rid of the valve on the hot outlet, which is _not_ safe.

Comment: how did it go today?

Comment: oops, updated the next post... I am in the middle of flushing out all of the sediment now, and next i am going to hook up the element while it is out of the tank (and while dipped in a tub of water, of course) to ensure its heating up...

Comment: Damn I wonder if it is excess salt buildup from the water softener?  check out the photo of the element i just put in 1 week ago... (thats salt residue on it....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the solution:

For some reason, the circuit was showing a reading of 120v on the multimeter. This led me to believe it was good. Since it is a 120v water heater, I went ahead and hooked it up to a nearby circuit which I KNOW was good. Sure enough, we had hot water within 45 minutes.

I am not sure how the multimeter read 120v if the circuit was bad.

Apparently water heater elements need extremely consistent and constant supply of power or else they won't heat up.

Problem Solved. Thanks for all of the pointers and advice.

Comment: Check the circuit for small breaks, loose connections, or charred wiring. small faults like that can allow the full voltage to pass through with a tiny load such as a multimeter, but then fail with a large current demand.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the unit?   http://www.gsw-wh.com/Docs/61515.1P.pdf

Page 6 figure 1 shows a reset button on the "High Limit" control that appears to be independent of the thermostat.   Is the "High Limit" control functioning correctly?   :)

Comment: Yes that document applies to this heater. However, as I view the figure 1, on page 6, I don't see where the high limit control is separate? The diagram simply breaks open the thermostat (which has 6 or so terminals in total). The two rectangle sections above the element are actually the entire thermostat. The thermostat has a reset button which I've tried already.

Comment: I was afraid of that, all being one piece.  :)   With the power off and both wires removed from the element, in ohms, what is the element resistance?   (I drove 40 miles to my cousins once - just to press a reset button he "knew" he'd reset!)

Comment: @120VAC 1500 watts, resistance across the element should be around 9.6 ohms.

Comment: There should be no reading (infinity) between either screw terminal and ground - the metal part of the water heater housing.  (I forgot there is only a five minute limit between edits and I'm fidgeting with other things.  (grin))

Comment: yep, i've checked all that, over and over :)  i get exactly 9.6 reading... could sediment buildup have anything to do with it? I am seriously grasping at straws here... I am on site all day today and tomorrow... I can take photos, etc... just let me know what I need to look for... I currently have it unhooked and doing multiple flushes. There seems to be a LOT of salty deposits (from water softener???) coming out...

Comment: Do you have access to an AC ammeter?   The ammeter will confirm the system is functioning electrically.   In this part of the world (the Ozarks hills) water heater tank gunk buildup is very common and easily detectible by the deep (low frequency) rumble of bubbling sounds after the water heater (gas or electric) is cooking for a while.  I don’t remember ever seeing a water heater consume energy without producing SOME amount of warm water though.   (Don't power it up unless full of water and any air bled out of the tank.)

Comment: One more question, can you detect any abnormal smells?   Not so much electrical, but gassing/reactions of the element?

Comment: (That's funny!   I'm so new here I just now realized the other post and all the other comments!  Sorry!)   Still, I'm anxious to hear your progress. (grin)